# How to combine multiple rows from different tables into a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get back **all** accounts registered in my database, with image filepaths for their 'profile' image and 'cover' image (facebook style). Image filepaths are stored in a different table to their `account` table.

My code is like this:

```
SELECT 
  a1.AccountID, 
 a1.Forename, 
  a1.Surname, 
  img1.Filename AS ProfileImg, 
  img2.Filename AS CoverImg
FROM
  dbo.Account a1
LEFT JOIN
  dbo.AccountImage img1 ON --table with images in
  img1.AccountID = a1.AccountID AND ProfileImg = 1 --boolean column to mark it as profile pic
LEFT JOIN
  dbo.AccountImage img2 ON --table with images in
  img2.AccountID = a1.AccountID and CoverImg = 1 --boolean column to flag as cover pic
```

Account table:

```
AccountID | Forename | Surname |
12345     | Ben      | Hur     |
12346     | Frodo    | Baggins |
12349     | Bill     | Gates   |
```

AccountImage table:

```
AccountID | Filename     | ProfileImg | CoverImg
12345     | face.jpg     | True       | NULL
12345     | bg.jpg       | NULL       | True
12346     | graph.png    | NULL       | NULL
12349     | sunset.jpg   | NULL       | True
```

This currently returns:

```
|AccountID|Forename|Surname|ProfileImg|CoverImg  |
|    12345|     Ben|    Hur|NULL      |bg.jpg    |
|    12345|     Ben|    Hur|face.jpg  |NULL      |
```

Result I need

```
|AccountID|Forename|Surname|ProfileImg|CoverImg  |
|    12345|     Ben|    Hur|face.jpg  |bg.jpg    |
```

I just want to return a single row for each `AccountID` which contains both their account details and image paths respectively (there are hundreds of accounts). Or else I end up with duplicate rows - one containing their `ProfileImg` filepath and one containing their `CoverImg` filepath.

Just to note - it is possible that they don't have a profile or cover pic. Which means both columns can be `NULL`.

Comment: Can you go with MAX(img1.Filename), MAX(img2.Filename) and Group by?

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but have you tried `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: I think it should work, as long as AccountID, Forename and Surname are same ... grouping will work

Comment: please give some sample data of these 3 tables. it shouldn't be the current return you gave us,  unless the  AccountImg got data like 2 rows for ProfileImg=1. 1 of them have filename is null and another filename is /filepath and i don't think that makes any sense

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke I have edited the question to include sample data of the Account and AccountImage tables

Comment: @Veljko89 yes it worked thank you my friend :) using max() and group by solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  a1.AccountID, 
 a1.Forename, 
  a1.Surname, 
  max(img1.Filename) AS ProfileImg, 
  max(img2.Filename) AS CoverImg
FROM
  dbo.Account a1
LEFT JOIN
  dbo.AccountImage img1 ON --table with images in
  img1.AccountID = a1.AccountID AND ProfileImg = 1 --boolean column to mark it as profile pic
LEFT JOIN
  dbo.AccountImage img2 ON --table with images in
  img2.AccountID = a1.AccountID and CoverImg = 2
GROUP BY 
 a1.AccountID, 
 a1.Forename, 
  a1.Surname
```

Comment: Worked very nicely thank you :). There is a typo in my original code which I updated. It should be `CoverImg = 1` because it is a boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

Just u have to use inner join instead of left join

```
SELECT 
  a1.AccountID, 
  a1.Forename, 
  a1.Surname, 
  img1.Filename AS ProfileImg, 
  img2.Filename AS CoverImg
FROM
  dbo.Account a1
INNER JOIN
  dbo.AccountImage img1 ON 
  img1.AccountID = a1.AccountID AND ProfileImg = 1 
INNER JOIN
  dbo.AccountImage img2 ON
  img2.AccountID = a1.AccountID and CoverImg = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a view that will do it. You will need to ensure that you have unique indexes set up on the account image table to prevent more than one image of each type being setup up on a particular account.

```
SELECT AccountID, Forename, Surname,
(SELECT TOP (1) Filename
FROM dbo.AccountImage
WHERE (AccountID = dbo.Account.AccountID) AND (ProfileImg <> 0)) AS ProfileImg,
(SELECT TOP (1) Filename
 FROM dbo.AccountImage AS AccountImage_2
 WHERE (AccountID = dbo.Account.AccountID) AND (CoverImg <> 0)) AS CoverImg
FROM dbo.Account
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.AccountImage AS AccountImage_1
WHERE (AccountID = dbo.Account.AccountID) AND (ProfileImg <> 0) OR
(AccountID = dbo.Account.AccountID) AND (CoverImg <> 0)) = 2)
```